# What's wrong with my SQL query? (mysql.user table)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This line isn't working well.

```
INSERT INTO `mysql`.`user` (`Host`, `User`, `ssl_cipher`, `x509_issuer`, `x509_subject`) VALUES ('%', 'User1', ?, ?, ?);
```

I'm try to do this trigger later, but first I need the correct insert.

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_user AFTER INSERT ON BBDD.users for each row INSERT INTO `mysql`.`user` (`Host`, `User`, `ssl_cipher`, `x509_issuer`, `x509_subject`, `authentication_string`) VALUES ('%', BBDD.users(name), ?, ?, ?, BBDD.users(password));
```

I use MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE.

Comment: Well you have some kind of prepared statement, but you never bind any values to the `?` placeholders.  Why would you expect this code to run?

Answer (score 0):

Don't insert something manually into system tables, unless you **really** know what you are doing (and from this question I doubt that's the case here). Instead use the designated commands, here `CREATE USER`.